# Include ":" character in parameter using Apache's mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, parameters

I use something like that to pass to the parameter 'text' what follows after the domain

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?text=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So if I have www.example.com/tralala I get $text='tralala'

But I want it to be possible to have in the parameter the character ":" multiple times:

www.example.com/me:you:him

Can you give me a hand?

If I test

```
www.example.com/me:you:him
```

I get the error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /you:me:him on this server.
```

Comment: It works for me. How did you test that rule?

Comment: ^(.*)$ would match 'me:you:him' so I don't really understand the question?

Comment: Try to use mod_rewrite’s logging feature (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+[\:a-z]+)$ index.php?text=$1 [L,QSA]
```

May require some tweeking. Although AFAIR the dot metacharacter matches any character except the dot itself, so you should be good with (.+) too.

Comment: The dot meta character matches any character, including the dot. And you don’t need to escape the `:`.